# Pandas: New column from conditions and from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, df1 and df2.

```
df1                df2
A   B              C   D   E
ad  df             ad  se  1
ad  se             xc  je  2
xc  je             ad  df  3
...                ...
```

I need to create a new column in **df1** with the values contained in column **E** from **df2**. For this, I need to find the matching values between columns **A** and **C**, and from  **B** and **D** from **df1** and **df2** respectively.

```
where A == C & B == D 
      XX = E
```

The result should be like this:

```
df1                
A   B   XX         
ad  df  3          
ad  se  1          
xc  je  2         
...
```

This might be straightforward but I'm quite new to pandas and haven't really found a way to accomplish this.

Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question(which is highly encouraged on SO), thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'C':'A', 'D':'B'}), on=['A', 'B'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want can be accomplished with a simple call to the `pd.merge` or `df.merge`.

Minimal example

```py
import pandas as pd
                                                                                       
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ad', 'ad', 'xc'], 'B': ['df', 'se', 'je']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['ad', 'xc', 'ad'], 'D': ['se', 'je', 'df'], 'E': [1, 2, 3]})
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
                                                                                       
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'])
```

Output

```py
    A   B   C   D  E
0  ad  df  ad  df  3
1  ad  se  ad  se  1
2  xc  je  xc  je  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can merge both the dataframes, based on the columns you mentioned.

```py
>>> result = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'])
>>> result
    A   B   C   D   E
0   ad  df  ad  df  3
1   ad  se  ad  se  1
2   xc  je  xc  je  2
```

And drop the columns `C` and `D`.

```py
result.drop(columns=['C', 'D'], inplace=True)
```

Else, a more elegant solution. Rename the columns from `C` and `D` to `A` and `B`, and you can just perform the `merge`.

````py
>>> result = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'C': 'A', 'D': 'B'}))
>>> result
    A   B   E
0   ad  df  3
1   ad  se  1
2   xc  je  2

```py
````